# StringBuilder deleteCharAt not working

Tags: java

```
    String s = "world";
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(s);
    str.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(s);
```

this code outputs the following result : world , what am i doing wrong ? why is the first character of string not being deleted ?

Comment: Because you printed out `s`, your original string, not `str`, the modified stringbuilder.

Comment: you are printing s

Comment: this is my first time using StringBuilder , thx for pointing this out !!

Comment: Did you expect string held by `s` to be modified or did you simply misprint `s` instead of `str`?

Comment: i was under the impression that the string passed to the string builder constructor will be modified

Comment: @Heythem But that would violate the general rule that `String` objects are immutable. Haven't they taught you that `String` is immutable yet? Which is why you need `StringBuilder` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue with the `StringBuilder` and your code is that it does not exactly what you think it does.

A `StringBuilder` may take any `CharSequence` as a constructor argument but it will not alter the passed value directly. String in particular are immutable. Anyway `StringBuilder`s do **not** alter the Object directly. They buffer the characters in a `char[]` which isn't immutable anymore.

To get the buffered value (and your new "altered" String) you have to call the [`toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.toString%28%29) method of the `StringBuilder` since it will create a new String based on the interally stored buffer.
But since it `System.out.println()` implicitly calls the `toString()` method it is not needed here.

```
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: You *don't* have to call `toString`: `System.out.println(str)` would work fine, because `System.out.println(Object)` will implicitly call it. The issue is not printing `str`, but rather `s`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah yes, forgot about the implicit invocation of the `toString()` method. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

you must put the value of your StringBuilder back to your string.

```
s = str.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing s, and s has not been changed. When you construct str using s, a copy of s is made. Told in a different way, the reference to each character in s and str is not the same, so even after your deletion in str, s stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
System.out.println(s);
```

to

```
System.out.println(str.toString());
```